# Are there any old paintings (medieval period onwards) that actually depict the female genitalia rather than just leaving the pubic region empty?

Tags: art

Of course, a lot has been said about the lack of female genitalia in e.g. Bouguereau's *The Birth of Venus* and so many other examples, but are there any examples from art between the end of the Middle Ages to the beginning of the 20th century of depictions of the nude female body that include the vulva?

Obviously excluding things where the actual subject of the painting *is* the vulva, *L'Origine du monde*, being the most famous example. I'm asking specifically about depictions of the nude female form where the focus isn't the pubic region.

Comment: Do the Triptych of Earthly Vanity and Divine Salvation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Memling#/media/File:Memling_Vanity_and_Salvation.jpg) suit your requeriments?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Sheela na gigs are medieval though  not paintings

Answer (score 4):

German-french TV channel Arte TV made a short film ([German](https://www.arte.tv/de/videos/100170-005-A/flick-flack/), [French](https://www.arte.tv/fr/videos/100170-005-A/gymnastique/)) about the practice of [Anasyrma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anasyrma), of lifting your skirt to publicly present your naked genitalia.

In the film, which starts with Gustave Courbet's painting *The origin of the world*, there are two more Flemish paintings from the 16th century:

- [The Persian women](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Persian_women,_by_Otto_van_Veen.jpg) by Otto van Veen,  and
- [The Bravery of the Persian Women](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:The_Bravery_of_the_Persian_Women.jpg) by Frans Francken the younger

Both paintings depict a scene from a story reported by Plutarch in his *Moralia*, where Persian women show their vulvae to fleeing Persian soldiers to [scare them back onto the battlefield](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Moralia/Bravery_of_Women*/A.html#V).

> At the time when Cyrus induced the Persians to revolt from king Astyages and the Medes he was defeated in battle. As the Persians were fleeing to the city, with the enemy not far from forcing their way in along with the Persians, the women ran out to meet them before the city, and, lifting up their garments, said, "Whither are you rushing so fast, you biggest cowards in the whole world? Surely you cannot, in your flight, slink in here whence you came forth." The Persians, mortified at the sight and the words, chiding themselves for cowards, rallied and, engaging the enemy afresh, put them to rout.

Both paintings make the genitalia a central part of the painting, but depict a considerably larger scene. While the reproduction of Francken's painting is not large enough to say for sure, the one of van Veen clearly details the vulvae.

Looking through depictions of van Veens work, there is also his [Amazones and Skythians](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Otto_van_Veen_-_Amazones_en_Skythen_-_GG_2667_-_Kunsthistorisches_Museum.jpg) with  the same level of detail.

Comment: _"Scare_ them back"? I could think of other motivations… ;) But in any case, this word choice is as I read it here imo quite, let's say 'odd' (if not very questionable for quite some reasons?). So can you please quote that part from your source? (As far as i understand that WP: 'they 'lured' them back to battle by promising to refuse 'further entry' for known cowards', or sth?)

Comment: @LаngLаngС I was more influenced by the videos (around 2:10), that say the soldiers were "shocked - and turned back". But after looking at the source, I stand by my interpretation.